# Como interromper um script em andamento com uma tecla?

Tags: python, loop, .exe

Fiz um script em um loop python que salva vários relatórios em pdf e o transformei em executável com o pyinstall. Quando termina de salvar, ele sai em segurança, mas caso eu não queira esperar até o final para poder sair, eu preciso fechar uma espécie de prompt que abre, mas daí buga tudo e ele continua fazendo comandos mesmo fechado e precisa matar o processo no gerenciador de tarefas... enfim, muito complicado para um usuário comum.

Queria saber se não tem uma forma de apertar um "ESC", por exemplo, e simplesmente sair em segurança do executável.

Já tentei Ctrl C, Ctrl D, PauseBreak... nada funciona

Segue um exemplo de sair de um loop pressionando uma tecla, mas eu preciso de algo mais sofisticado, pois isso só funcionaria depois que executasse tudo que tem dentro do while, mas eu preciso que interrompa na hora que eu quiser. Se tivesse um key is NOT pressed, ou algo do tipo, seria uma maravilha, pois colocaria o script dentro dessa condição e na hora que apertasse a tecla, iria quebrar o loop.

```
a = 0

while a == 0:
   print('oi mundo')
   time.sleep(1)
   if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
      a = 1
      print('saiu')


sys.exit()
```

EDIT:

A solução do Zé Reis foi muito boa!! Mas tem um problema: eu tenho um for dentro do while, e aí esse método não funciona. Olha o exemplo:

```
while a['value'] == 0:
    # do something
    b =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    print('>>> Olá Mundo')
    for n in b:
        print(n)
        time.sleep(1)
    time.sleep(1)

print('Saiu')
```

o resultado é o seguinte

```
>>> Olá Mundo
1
2
qVocê pressionou a tecla
3
4
q5
6
7
q8
9
Saiu
```

como pode ver, apertei 'q' 3 vezes, mas ele só saiu no final do for. Você sabe como solucionar isso? De qualquer forma, muito obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minha solução para isso foi criar uma função separada para monitorar apenas o pressed da key rodando em Thread, e transformei a variavel `a` em um `dicionário` pois da forma em que ela estava a alteração de seu valor não funcionou de forma correta, ficou da seguinte forma:

```
import keyboard, time, sys
from threading import Thread

a = {"value": 0}

def monitorKey():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            print('Você pressionou a tecla')
            a['value'] += 1 
            break                       


Thread(target = monitorKey).start()

b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

while a['value'] == 0:
    print('>>> Olá Mundo')
    for n in b:        
        #Condição de parada
        if(a['value'] != 0):
            break
        print(n)
        time.sleep(1)

    time.sleep(1)       

print('Saiu')
```

Comment: Muito boa a solução!! Mas olha o EDIT e vê o que tu acha, por favor!!

Comment: @johnata reveja minha alteração, acho que isso resolve seu problema!

Comment: Cara, resolve em parte, porque só funciona quando volta pro começo do 'for', se eu apertar depois da segunda linha do for, ele vai executar todos os comandos que restarem, e só vai dar o break quando voltar pro começo do laço. Como meu script está na maior parte dentro de um 'for', eu teria que colocar esse 'if' várias vezes ao longo do 'for'.